# Java use synchronized and volatile when manipulating multiple properties and locking on a lock object

Tags: java, synchronization, volatile

I need to manipulate multiple properties in Java while keeping them in sync.

Is this code correct (from my understanding this is):

```
class X {
    private final Object lockObject = new Object();
    private int a;
    private boolean b;
    private Y y;

    public void doStuff(int i) {
          synchronized (lockObject) {
                a = i;
                b = a == 8;
                y.someMethod(b);
                y = new Y(a, y);
          }
    }
}
```

Does this `synchronized` block ensure updates to all properties or just the locked property are written (in which case it would not really make sense to lock on a final object with no state)?

Or do I need to use `volatile` in order to ensure memory visibility updates on all threads:

```
class X {
    private final Object lockObject = new Object();
    private volatile int a;
    private volatile boolean b;
    private volatile Y y;

    public void doStuff(int i) {
          synchronized (lockObject) {
                a = i;
                b = a == 8;
                y.someMethod(b);
                y = new Y(a, y);
          }
    }
}
```

I am actually 99% sure the first one is correct but not a 100%, thanks for answers.

Comment: If that’s the only method of the class, there is no need to store `a` and `b` in fields at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first.

But, only in interactions between other threads that *also* lock on this lock object. In other words, if 10 threads all call `doStuff` simultaneously:

- Those 10 threads each run the code there in some undefined order.
- Each of the 10 executions sees the updates of the previous execution, and will run its execution as an atomic unit (i.e. the `a == 8` check will see its own `a = i`, guaranteed, as the state of `a`.

There is no need to *also* declare those fields `volatile`.